# Does anyone know how to edit a Macro created in mobaxterm?

Tags: macros, mobaxterm

I have a macro that I recorded thinking I could go back and edit it.  But I can't seem to find a way to edit it.  There is a macro button but it only runs the macro. I've looked in the mobaxterm directory on my PC, but can't find it there either.  This is running on a windows7 laptop.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
She

Answer (score 8):

Right-click on the macro button that you are using to run it (in the macros side-bar) and there will be a context menu that has an option to edit it.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do it from the menu bar, which doesn't work. Doing it from the side-bar is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in the latest version is:

1. Stop MobaXterm.
2. Locate the MobaXterm directory.
3. Open the MobaXterm.ini file.
4. Locate the following config sections

   [Macros]

   [MacrosHotkeys]
5. Delete the entry of the macro you want to modify in above setsions.
6. Save the file
7. Restart MobaXterm.

Answer (score 1):

In Professional Edition ver 20.3 click on Macros tab on the left side of the screen. It will show you all your Macros.

Now right click on your Macro and Edit it or Assign Keyboard Shortcut to it.